# ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' on using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I made a connection between mysql and python using mysql-connector-python. The code words fine when I run it as a script but gives an error

`ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' on running the exe. file made using pyinstaller.`

How do I resolve this?
Here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector

client = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'address', user = 'username', password = 'password')
executer = client.cursor()

executer.execute("use db;")
executer.execute("select * from db;")
out = executer.fetchall()
print(out)

client.close()
```

[output of .exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIQzo.png)